# How to make chrome search engine independent of my GEO location?

Tags: google-chrome, vpn, search, geolocation

I use a VPN service and whenever I turn it on, my chrome browser uses `google.ro` as its search engine when I type my query into address bar. Please suggest a way to make it always use `google.com` instead of other variants. (Both because of language and sometimes less relevant results by those google variants)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A) Drop this into your Everything bar https://www.google.ca/search?q=
and type your search term after the = key for a one time use.

B) To make the change permanent, click on the triple-stacked-dot menu at upper right, and choose **Settings**, then scroll down to Search Engine. Click on **Manage Search Engines** and add **https://www.google.ca/search?q=** then, after adding, click on the triple-stacked-dot on the right side of the Google.Ca entry, and choose **Make Default**.

C) A third option is to edit your settings at Google.com, but I am uncertain as to whether deleting cookies would erase this change, and the result requires you login with your Google login: Go to https://www.google.com/preferences?hl=en&fg=1 and scroll down to nearly the bottom. Select **United States** then **Save**.

Comment: This is axiomatic in fact but I want chrome to do this automatically every time for my comfort.

Comment: I believe the op wants `.com` rather than `.ca`

Comment: I suggested .ca because I have seen proxy servers replace the .com with the local national variant, but .ca results are virtually identical to .com results. However, I found a better solution, in my revised answer.